# How to maintain the single property in ngrx/store in angular application and update the value through dispatching the action?

Tags: angular, action, ngrx, ngrx-store, state-management

i am working in angular project and need to implement ngrx/store for particular module. I want maintain a single property named 'page' as the initial state in my reducer function as mentioned below:

reducer.ts:

```
import { createReducer ,on } from '@ngrx/store';
import { setCurrentPage } from './orders.action';

export const initialState : number = 1;

export const orderReducer = createReducer(
    initialState,
    on(
        setCurrentPage,
        () => {
            // logic for updatig the inital state with the value dispatch from this Action
            return 1;
        } 
    )
)
```

The problem is when i try to mention the props<number>() in  the Action file as below:

action.ts:

It shows the error as below:

[image]

So i want to know whether i can implement the props as number or not? If not why?

Comment: If you look at the error closely, it is saying you cannot create an action with empty properties.  Try removing "props<number>()" from the action declaration.

Comment: props<{ page: any}>(),

Comment: You forgot to include your action.ts?

Answer (score 1):

The error mentions that you need to wrap it in an object.

```
const setCurrentPage = createAction('NAME', props<{ page: number}>());

on(setCurrentPage, (action) => action.page);
```